# Confusion about printing (an integer with multiple digits) in Assembly (NASM)

Tags: assembly, nasm

So I'm a beginner in assembly and I'm currently going over some tutorials on YT, and now I'm going over an exercise that
is supposed to print an integer. Now, I understood the algorithm behind all this code, or more exactly, the process on how it
actually prints that integer. The problem is, I'm not sure if it is *exactly* how I imagine it to be in terms of code.

For instance, I am given digitSp, that will hold the integer, and digitSpPos that is supposed to act as a sort of index. Then I
move the integer into RAX and call _printRAX. So far seems quite clear to me. The confusion starts when I get into the _printRAX
label: here, as far as I've understood, I'm adding a line feed value at the address pointed by RCX, then we increment the value
in RCX and finally we transfer that value in digitSpPos. All of this is pretty confusing because I don't know exactly how it is
supposed to work: My goal somehow would be to add a line feed and increment the "index", and then pass the updated index into
digitSpPos. But is it how it happens? For instance, when I do , I am simply transfering 100 bytes into rcx,
so when I do , I should get 101? And when I do , that moves the line feed value at the address pointed by
RCX, while I thought digitSp would hold the whole string, which has been already passed to RCX as value.

In the following two loops, again, the confusing part is only in the section when I basically do the same thing as in _printRAX
(I update my "index" and move the numbers one by one). All in all, the whole idea would be to divide the integer by 10 and take
each remainder and stick it into RCX until I recreate the number, but in reverse. Then, I print everything from the end of RCX
to the beginning (giving me the integer in the correct order, plus the line feed).

But questions are, why do I use digitSp if RCX is going to hold the whole integer? Why do I pass each number into as a value
in the address pointed by RCX? Has it something to do on how the registers view those bytes assigned to them?

I apologize if my question is a bit weird, but I would really like to understand how everything really works, since as a beginner,
that would help me grasp the idea behind assembly programming better. I usually analyze every program and try to make sense out of
it, but now apparently I've gotten into a bit of a problem.

The code is as follows:

```
section .bss
 digitSp resb 100
 digitSpPos resb 8

section .text
 global _start

_start:
 mov rax, 12345
 call _printRAX

 mov rax, 60
 mov rdi, 0
 syscall

_printRAX:
 mov rcx, digitSp
 mov rbx, 10
 mov [rcx], rbx
 inc rcx
 mov [digitSpPos], rcx

_printRAXLoop:
 mov rdx, 0
 mov rbx, 10
 div rbx
 ;push rax
 add rdx, 48

 ;mov rcx, [digitSpPos]
 mov [rcx], dl
 inc rcx
 mov [digitSpPos], rcx

 ;pop rax
 cmp rax, 0
 jne _printRAXLoop

_printRAXLoop2:
 ;mov rcx, [digitSpPos]

 mov rax, 1
 mov rdi, 1
 mov rsi, rcx
 mov rdx, 1
 syscall

 mov rcx, [digitSpPos]
 dec rcx
 mov [digitSpPos], rcx

 cmp rcx, digitSp
 jge _printRAXLoop2

 ret
```

There are a few commented lines because, as I analyzed the code from the tutorial, those lines seemed to be redundant (and checking that by running the program, they apparently were), but I left them in case I could actually be wrong.

Comment: The `'\n'` has an ASCII value of `0xa` or just `10`. You are apparently using the RCX register to multiply by `10` (e.g. `721 = 1 + (2 x 10) + (7 x 10 x 10)`), etc.. Your counter will hold the number of time the digit is multiplied by `10` (by a newline) before being added to the current sum. There are a couple of schemes for this. Don't let the newline throw you off, it's just the number `10`.

Comment: My problem was more with operations like *mov [rcx], rbx*, *inc rcx* and *mov [digitSpPos], rcx*. The main idea is that I don't actually get why do I use *mov rcx, digitSp* (digitSp is supposed to be where I store my number) but then I add my line feed with *mov [rcx], rbx*, adding it in RCX using [] (I don't get the relationship between these two operations, and how it helps to the final result). Also, when I increment RCX, like I said above, shouldn't I get values bigger than 100 every time? So digitSpPos should be also getting those values?

Comment: Oh.. That all has to do with addressing. Take `mov rcx, digitSp`, you are putting the address for the 100-byte buffer in `rcx`. `mov rbx, 10`, puts `10` in `rbx` (no mystery). `mov [rcx], rbx` moves the contents of `rbx` (`10`) and stores it at the address currently in `[rcx]` (the 1st-byte of `digitSp`), then `inc rcx` increments the address in `rcx` so it now holds the address of the 2nd-byte in `digitSp` and `mov [digitSpPos], rcx` stores that address in `digitSpPos` and so on. [x86 Assembly Guide](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html) is useful here.

Comment: I see. After playing a bit with the program in gdb I see how all of this works. Well, glad I figured it out, although it is a fairly simple matter, for a beginner it is always good to never let things uncovered. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: There is nothing simple about the addressing rules in assembly for the beginner (or old buzzard who hasn't fluently written in 25 years). While the rules themselves are limited to what combinations of immediate, register and memory addressed can be combined in any one instruction, how you handle and where you temporarily store information (or pointers to it) takes quite a bit of practice before it becomes second nature. Good luck with your coding.